# Ansible AWS: Unable to connect to EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ansible

## What I want to achieve

I want to create an EC2 instance with LAMP stack installed using one Ansible playbook.

## Problem

The instance creation works fine, and I can modify it in the EC2 Console, but the problem appears when trying to access the instance for example install apache or create keys.

This is the error:

> fatal: [35.154.26.86]: UNREACHABLE! => {
>       "changed": false, 
>       "msg": "[Errno None] Unable to connect to port 22 on  or 35.154.26.86", 
>       "unreachable": true
>   }

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziVVi.png)

## Code

This is my playbook:

```
---
- name: Power up an ec2 with LAMP stack installed
  hosts: localhost
  become: true
  become_user: root
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    keypair: myKeyPair
    security_group: launch-wizard-1
    instance_type: t2.micro
    image: ami-47205e28
    region: x-x-x
  tasks:
    - name: Adding Python-pip
      apt: name=python-pip state=latest

    - name: Install Boto Library
      pip: name=boto

    - name: Launch instance (Amazon Linux)
      ec2:
         key_name: "{{ keypair }}"
         group: "{{ security_group }}"
         instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
         image: "{{ image }}"
         wait: true
         region: "{{ region }}"
         aws_access_key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
         aws_secret_key: "Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      register: ec2

    - name: Print all ec2 variables
      debug: var=ec2

    - name: Add all instance public IPs to host group
      add_host: hostname={{ item.public_ip }} groups=ec2hosts
      with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"


- hosts: ec2hosts
  remote_user: ec2-user
  become: true
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
#I need help here, don't know what to do.
    - name: Create an EC2 key
      ec2_key:
        name: "privateKey"
        region: "x-x-x"
        register: ec2_key

    - name: Save private key
      copy: content="{{ ec2_key.private_key }}" dest="./privateKey.pem" mode=0600
      when: ec2_key.changed

    # The Rest is installing LAMP
```

## Information:

1- My hosts file is default.

2- I used this command to run the playbook:

> sudo ansible-playbook lamp.yml -vvv -c paramiko

3- launch-wizard-1 has SSH.

4- myKeyPair is a public key imported from my device to the console(don't know if this is ok)

5- I am a big newbie

Comment: Why don't you follow example from the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/ec2_module.html)? Note the _Wait for SSH to come up_ task. And the next problem you will bump into is `ec2_key` execution on remote host.

Comment: Does the port 22 is open in your security groupe ?if yes, can you share  your hosts file ?

Answer (score 0):

Ansible requires `Python` installed on VM to work.

Here is your required code:

```
  - name: upload an ssh keypair to ec2
    hosts: localhost
    connection: local
    gather_facts: False
    vars:
      keypair_name: Key_name
      key_material: "{{ lookup('file', 'keyfile') }}"
      region: "{{ region }}"


    tasks:
      - name: ssh keypair for ec2
        ec2_key:
          aws_access_key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          aws_secret_key: "Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          region: "{{ region }}"
          name: "{{ keypair_name }}"
          key_material: "{{ key_material }}"
          state: present


  - name: Power up an ec2 with LAMP stack installed
    hosts: localhost
    become: true
    become_user: root
    gather_facts: False
    vars:
      keypair: myKeyPair
      security_group: launch-wizard-1
      instance_type: t2.micro
      image: ami-47205e28
      region: x-x-x
      my_user_data: |   # install Python: Ansible needs Python pre-installed on the instance to work!
        #!/bin/bash
        sudo apt-get install python -y

    tasks:
      - name: Adding Python-pip
        apt: name=python-pip state=latest

      - name: Install Boto Library
        pip: name=boto

      - name: Launch instance (Amazon Linux)
        ec2:
           key_name: "{{ keypair }}"
           group: "{{ security_group }}"
           instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
           image: "{{ image }}"
           wait: true
           wait_timeout: 300
           user_data: "{{my_user_data}}"
           region: "{{ region }}"
           aws_access_key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
           aws_secret_key: "Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        register: ec2

      - name: Add all instance public IPs to host group
        add_host: hostname={{ item.public_ip }} groups=ec2hosts
        with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"
```