# Unable to connect to AWS instance even after manually adding in public key to authorized_keys

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, ansible, boto, boto3

I am unable to run an ansible-playbook or use ansible ping on a AWS instance. However, I can ssh into the instance with no problem. My hosts file is this:

`[instance]
xx.xx.xxx.xxx ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/josh/Ansible/Amazon/AWS.pem`

Should I not use a direct path. I am trying to use ansible to install apache onto the server. In my security group in the AWS console, I allowed all incoming ssh traffic in port 22, and ansi
      service: name=apache2 state=started`ble tries to ssh through port 22 so that should not be the problem. Is there some crucial idea behind sshing into instances that I didn't catch onto to. I tried following this post: [Ansible AWS: Unable to connect to EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45363067/ansible-aws-unable-to-connect-to-ec2-instance) but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure inside **ansible.cfg** ***

> private_key_file = path of private key(server-private-key)

---

and in host machine don't change default authorized_keys file ,better way is create one user, for that user create .ssh directory and then inside create a file called authorized_keys & paste your server-public key

> $~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Answer (score -1):

try:  ansible-playbook yourplaybookname.yml --connection=local

## ansible defaults to ssh